# Just installed Ubuntu and during boot am given a choice but unable to choose

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

i decided to try out this Linux thing, so i installed Ubuntu. Unfortunately after it completed the installation a final reboot happened after which i was prompted a choice for which OS i'd like to use: Windows 8.1 or Ubuntu, on the screen was also written how to navigate between the choices (using arrow keys) which after trying brought no results, and since it automatically chooses the selected option after 8 seconds, and the default choice is windows 8.1, i thought that maybe i ran out of time so i restarted again and tried navigating to the other choice "Ubuntu", again unsuccessfully. The third time i restarted i tried out clicking either Tab or F8 because these two buttons were suppose to do something, and yet again - no response. My guess is that there's something wrong with detecting my keyboard but that's just a newbie guess, so i'd really appreciate any help i can get, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a USB keyboard & plugged into a PCI expansion card then try in mobo's I/O panel directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i tried that and it worked, although now i have a followup question: is it possible to not need to have my keyboard connected into the front panel and if so, how?

Comment: When I say I/O, it will be at the back (vertical), but not a PCI card (horizontal.) May have to free up other USB cables.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your BIOS if devices are booted during boot (you have to disable all types of "quick boot", even "Windows quick boot").

Comment: thanks for the answer, although i'd like to ask you if you could give me directions on how to check my BIOS to see whether or not my devices are being booted during system boot, thanks in advance